# Power BI- DAX measure-Table Condition based on the multiple if

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have a 2 tables, Table 1 is "Data" and Table 2 is "Rule". How can I apply multiple if condition based on the table condition in Power BI?

**Table-Data-(Column A, B and C is my Raw data)**

Column A contain Text (Code)
Column B contain Number (Usage)
Column C contain Text (Usage Unit)
Column D output for usage column
Column E output for usage Unit column

Note: column D and E my output column based on the column A to C

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stqb0.png)

**Table 2- Rule-(This is my condition table for usage and usage unit according to the code**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CndD7.png)

Column A contain the following code "MII", "KKR", "CHE" and "RCB" then usage column can not be blanks or 0 and usage unit column must be blanks for the code "MII" and the remaining codes usage unit can be blanks or the usage unit must be match the following two codes "DMK" or BJP".

Column A contain the following code "001", "KXP", "SRH","DEL" and "RRL" then usage column must be blanks and usage unit column must be blanks as well.

**Example;**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxOD7.png)

code    Usage  UsageUnit Usage(Output)  Usage unit(Output)

001     0.00              Okay            Okay
001     1.00      DMK     Not okay        Not okay
MII     0.00      BJP     Not okay        Not Okay
MII     1.00              OKAY            OKAY

**Additional condition** for usage columns has 999 then usage output is "xx".

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cozopedtucklomu/CONDITION%20MATCH.xlsx?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k68p2mru6yqob6z/CINDITION-MATCH.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SWITCH in your CalculatedColumn/Measure. The first argument is TRUE(), second -> our condition evaluated to true, third output, forth, next condition, fifth, output and so on.

```
SWITCH (
TRUE(),
'DATA'[Code] in {"MII", "KKR", "CHE", "RCB"} && NOT(ISBLANK('DATA'[USAGE]), "ConditionOuptput",
'DATA'[Code] in {"001", "KXP", "SRH","DEL" ,"RRL"} && ISBLANK('DATA'[USAGE]), "SecondConditionOutput",
"Else goes here"
```

)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help and sorry for the late reply. I will follow-up your advise and update the feedback. can I get email notification if someone answered my question because I missed your message so I am unbale to respond on-time? Could you please advise